# aws_role_arn not being used for Terraform Vault provider in auth_login_aws

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-vault

I'm hoping to contribute some documentation on `auth_login_aws` because I'm trying to use the feature described in this [feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-vault/issues/1187).
TL;DR, despite specifying `aws_role_arn` in the snippet below, the provider is still trying to use the credentials in my `~.aws/credentials` file.

```
provider "vault" {
  address = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
  skip_child_token = true
  auth_login_aws {
    role = "dev-role-corey-iam"
    header_value = "vault.example.com"
    aws_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/SomeRole"
    aws_role_session_name = "corey-test-session"
    aws_region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to get Terraform to pull secrets from a local Vault instance using the SomeRole IAM role, which is bound to the dev-role-corey-iam Auth role. I'm currently logged in with a different AWS IAM role (PrimaryRole) that can assume the SomeRole role. When I run `terraform plan`, the provider is using PrimaryRole instead when I expect it to use SomeRole because `aws_role_arn` is specified. Am I misinterpreting what `aws_role_arn` should do?